# Swift4 Bottom sheet custom XIB file

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, cocoapods, swift4

I want to display bottom sheet full screen using my custom **Login.xib**. Already i tried [this library](https://github.com/hryk224/Bottomsheet).

```
let controller = Bottomsheet.Controller()
controller.initializeHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I this code i need to add my Login.swift file please any one help me.
Expecting output like this.
I am fresher in IOS so i tried my best also.[image].

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var firstName: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    firstName.text = "Vinothkumar"
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
    return UINib(nibName: "LoginView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
}}
```

Comment: you need to give the view to the controller, you have not given the view to the controller

Comment: Can you please elaborate.

Comment: controller.view = UIView()

this is what i am talking about, you need to initialize your view , either from a xib or  create a UIView and assign it to controller.view

Comment: It's working fine thats for your information.

Comment: If i use .xib when i click close icon that time dismiss my BottomSheet.

Comment: great, an upvote on the would be nice, thanks.

Comment: dismiss(self, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: In my UIViewController class inside my button click are not working.@ShahzaibQureshi

Comment: Any declare i did in my class like @IBOutlet weak var firstName: UILabel!, that time facing "class is not key value coding-compliant for the key firstName" issue. Above i added my code.

Comment: try reconnecting the outlets

Comment: I tried many times but same error.